# Why do I get two different results from the same code?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm wondering why I am getting two different results from this code that I am using from github.  If I run the compiled package on my cell phone, I get a barcode readout of 991245243.  However if I use my computer, the readout is 0991245243.  Can anyone explain why?

What I am trying to do is have the results from the barcode scanner check against a spreadsheet and then return the results from the adjacent cells.  I want to look for exact matches because it could be catastrophic if multiple results are found and they conflict.

```
# Kivy OpenCV Barcode Scanner
# done by Vijeth P H 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import webbrowser
import cv2

# Create global variables, for storing and displaying barcodes
outputtext=''
weblink=''
leb=Label(text=outputtext,size_hint_y=None,height='48dp',font_size='45dp')
found = set()       # this will not allow duplicate barcode scans to be stored
togglflag=True

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    # first screen that is displayed when program is run
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'  # vertical placing of widgets
        
        self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)    # start OpenCV camera
        self.cam.set(3,1280)        # set resolution of camera
        self.cam.set(4,720)
        self.img=Image()        # Image widget to display frames
        
        # create Toggle Button for pause and play of video stream
        self.togbut=ToggleButton(text='Pause',group='camstart',state='down',size_hint_y=None,height='48dp',on_press=self.change_state)
        self.but=Button(text='Stop',size_hint_y=None,height='48dp',on_press=self.stop_stream)
        self.add_widget(self.img)
        self.add_widget(self.togbut)
        self.add_widget(self.but)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1.0/30)     # update for 30fps
        
                
    # update frame of OpenCV camera
    def update(self,dt):
        if togglflag:
            ret, frame = self.cam.read()    # retrieve frames from OpenCV camera
            
            if ret:
                buf1=cv2.flip(frame,0)      # convert it into texture 
                buf=buf1.tostring()
                image_texture=Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]),colorfmt='bgr')
                image_texture.blit_buffer(buf,colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt='ubyte')
                self.img.texture=image_texture  # display image from the texture
                
                barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)     # detect barcode from image
                for barcode in barcodes:
                    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
                    barcodeType = barcode.type
                    weblink=barcodeData
                    text = "{} ({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)
                    cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    if barcodeData not in found:    # check if detected barcode is a duplicate
                        outputtext=text
                        leb.text=outputtext         # display the barcode details
                        found.add(barcodeData)
                        self.change_screen()
                
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord("q"):
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    exit(0)
        
    # change state of toggle button
    def change_state(self,*args):
        global togglflag
        if togglflag:
            self.togbut.text='Play'
            togglflag=False
        else:
            self.togbut.text='Pause'
            togglflag=True
            
            
    def stop_stream(self,*args):
        self.cam.release()  # stop camera
        
    def change_screen(self,*args):
        main_app.sm.current='second'    # once barcode is detected, switch to second screen
    
class SecondScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'
        self.lab1=Label(text='Output: ',size_hint_y=None,height='48dp',font_size='45dp')
        self.but1=Button(text='Open in Web Browser',on_press=self.open_browser,size_hint_y=None,height='48dp')
        self.add_widget(self.lab1)
        self.add_widget(leb)
        self.add_widget(self.but1)
        
    def open_browser(self,*args):
        webbrowser.open(weblink)       # this opens link in browser
        
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm=ScreenManager()     # screenmanager is used to manage screens
        self.mainsc=MainScreen()
        scrn=Screen(name='main')
        scrn.add_widget(self.mainsc)
        self.sm.add_widget(scrn)
        
        self.secondsc=SecondScreen()
        scrn=Screen(name='second')
        scrn.add_widget(self.secondsc)
        self.sm.add_widget(scrn)
        
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app=TestApp()
    main_app.run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a picture as requested.
[image: barcode example]

Comment: Care to show the barcode, please.

Comment: Added picture as requested

Comment: The barcode in the picture apparently has the value 9571114556, which doesn't seem to match your readout.

Comment: Correct.  I scan it with my phone and it reads 9571114556.  I scan it with my laptop camera and it reads 09571114556.  If I scan it with a barcode gun from a computer, it reads 9571114556.

Comment: 9571114556 is that barcode scanned as UPC.  09571114556 is that barcode scanned as EAN.  I guess you just need to be more specific about the symbology to use.

Comment: Then why does the above code read it as a UPC on my phone and EAN 13 on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

As the behaviors of the reader on the two platforms differ, and the decoding is wrong, one can suspect a bug in the reader that causes access to uninitialized memory. (If the problem was just a misread, not a bug, the texts would be strictly identical.)

Or can it be that the text display clips off the first character on the phone ?

---

**Update:**

The new information that on one platform the code is said to be an EAN13 and on the other a UPC-A explains the extra 0. (You should have said it upfront.) The two barcode standards require a slight difference in the way the number is reported.

But this does not explain why the code is completely wrong and why different symbologies are reported. (Maybe the default settings are different on the two patforms.)

Comment: I just used pyinstaller to build it and it still gives me the EAN13 code.

Comment: @Patrick: the picture shows an UPC-A.

Comment: Right.  So it might be a camera issue. I ran it through pycharm, built the app in windows, ran it in a Linux vm.